# AXIOS Post not working with REACT application in Internet Explorer

Tags: reactjs, post, axios, internet-explorer-11

**Note:** I do have a solution for this already, I wanted to provide it here as a Question/Answer so if others run into this issue they can see if what works for me will also work for them.

**What I'm trying to do:**
I've been working on a REACT application that needs to send data to a Java Servlet.
Looking online I saw AXIOS being recommended to make Post commands to do just that.

**The Issue:**
I have the following code that works fine in Edge, Chrome and Firefox, but fails in Internet Explorer (with the error being **URLSearchParams** not being found in IE's browser console)

```
        let axiosConfig = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        };            
        // Putting together the data to be passed to the java servlet.
        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('var1', this.state.data1);
        params.append('var2', this.state.data2);

        var urlToPost = 'https://localhost:8080/someServlet/someMethod';

        axios.post(urlToPost, params, axiosConfig)
            .then((res) => {
                // Handling Response from Servlet.
                console.log("AXIOS POST RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", res);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                // Handler exception error thrown by Servlet.
                alert('Error during submission');
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

There was several suggestions I saw online on how to resolve it, and there was some that "worked" in IE, meaning I got no error on the IE Browser console, but when the data reached the Java Servlet the extracted data fields were null.

So to the point the solution for me was to use jQuery to do the post when using Internet Explorer, as such:

```
       // This if statement checks to see if the user's browser is Internet Explorer
       // if its true then use jQuery to do the POST
       if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") !== -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode === true )) //IF IE > 10
       {
           var myObject = {
              var1: this.state.data1,
              var2: this.state.data2
            };
            var urlToPost = 'https://localhost:8080/someServlet/someMethod';
            $.post(urlToPost, myObject, 
                function(result) {  
                   // handle response
               })
              .done(function(result) {
                   // handle response
              })
              .fail(function(result) {
                  // handle response
              })
              .always(function(result) {
                 // handle response
              });

       } else {
        // use the AXIOS POST command code from my initial question above
       }
```

Before doing that I had to install jquery and promise by using the following commands:

> npm install jquery
>
> npm install es6-promise

Then at the top of my react file I had to include the following imports:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import { polyfill } from 'es6-promise'; polyfill();
```

With those changes Internet Explorer did not give me any more console errors, and the Java Servlet I have was able to extract non-null data from the HTTP Response object.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need a polyfill for `URLSearchParams` in IE

https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-search-params-polyfill